# setState() does not stop rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I want to update `useState` array values by calling a function that maps through an array (called from the database) and the `useState` array will be updated for each item in the (database array) so I have tried the following approach:

```
const [snapshots, setSnapshots] = useState();
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

// ***  get from the database ***** //

useEffect(()=> {
    db.collection("users").doc("4sfrRMB5ROMxXDvmVdwL").collection("basket")
     .get()
     .then((snapshot) => {
      setSnapshots(snapshot.docs)            
     }
    ) ; 
}, []);

  // ***  get from the database ***** //

  // ***  update items value ***** //
  return <div className="cart__items__item">
            {snapshots && snapshots.map((doc)=>(
            setItems([...items, doc.data().id]),
            console.log(items)
               ))
             }
          </div>   
   // ***  update items value ***** //
```

but the following error appears:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I have tried to `console.log` the result to see the check the issue and the `Items` array was logged in the console continuously I have tried to include the code in a `useEffect`  but it did not work as well .

Comment: useEffect(()=>{setItems(“updated value”)},[ ]) this probably should work.  Pass empty dependency array so it only runs after mounting(runs once)

Comment: Do not mutate state inside the render function. Commonly you'll call it reacting to a user action (event), or inside a useEffect after a mutation of a prop. By calling it directly in the render function you are calling the function itself recursively.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: You don't need to call setState here, you already  set its value in the useState.  All you have done here is create an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never call a state setter at the top level of your component function. With function components, the key thing to remember is that when you change state, your function will get called again with the updated state. If your code has a state change at the top level of the function (as yours does in the question), every time the function runs, you change state, causing the function to run, causing another state change, and so on, and so on. In your code:

```
const initialArray  = [];                        // *** 1
const [Items, setItems] = useState(initialArray) // *** 2
initialArray.push("pushed item")
setItems(initialArray)                           // *** 3
```

1. Creates a new array every time
2. Only uses the first one to set the initial value of `Items` when the component is created
3. Sets new array in state, causing the function to be called again

Instead, you should be setting state only in response to some change or event, such as a click handler, or some other state changing, etc.

Also note that you must not directly modify an object (including an array) that you have in state. Your code doesn't technically do that (since there's a new `initialArray` every time), but it looks like what you meant to do. To add to an array in state, you *copy* the array and add the new entry at the end.

An example of the above:

```
function Example() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const clickHandler = e => {
        setItems([...items, e.currentTarget.value]);
    };
    return <div>
        <div>
            {items.map(item => <div key={item}>{item}</div>)}
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="A" onClick={clickHandler} />
        <input type="button" value="B" onClick={clickHandler} />
        <input type="button" value="C" onClick={clickHandler} />
    </div>;
}
```

*(Slightly odd UI just to keep the code example simple.)*

Note that conventionally `Items` would be called `items`.

---

Re your update:

- That code calls `setItems` at the top level of the function, so it has the problem above. Instead, you do that work in the `useEffect` querying the database.
- There's no reason to call `setItems` repeatedly during the `map` operation.
- The code should handle the component unmounting while the DB operation is outstanding
- The code should actually render something in the `map` in the JSX
- The code should handle errors (rejections)

E.g., something like this:

```
const [snapshots, setSnapshots] = useState();
const [items, setItems] = useState();   // *** If you're going to use `undefined`
                                        // as the initial state of `snapshots`,
                                        // you probably want to do the same with
                                        // `items`

useEffect(()=> {
    let cancelled = false;
    db.collection("users").doc("4sfrRMB5ROMxXDvmVdwL").collection("basket")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        // *** Don't try to set state if we've been unmounted in the meantime
        if (!cancelled) {
            setSnapshots(snapshot.docs);
            // *** Create `items` **once** when you get the snapshots
            setItems(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().id));
        }
    })
    // *** You need to catch and handle rejections
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report error...
    });
    return () => {
        // *** The component has been unmounted. If you can proactively cancel
        // the outstanding DB operation here, that would be best practice.
        // This sets a flag so that it definitely doesn't try to update an
        // unmounted component, either because A) You can't cancel the DB
        // operation, and/or B) You can, but the cancellation occurred *just*
        // at the wrong time to prevent the promise fulfillment callback from
        // being queued. (E.g., you need it even if you can cancel.)
        cancelled = true;
    };
}, []);

// *** Use `items` here
return <div className="cart__items__item">
    {items && items.map(id => <div>{id}</div>)/* *** Or whatever renders ID */}
</div>;
```

Note that that code assumes that `doc.data().id` is a synchronous operation.

Comment: Ok but the click handler part does not work for me because I want to run this code inside a function that maps through an array (called from the database)  and the items array will be updated for each element in that array so it will face the same issue  @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @MohammadAmjad - We can only answer the question you write, which had nothing about any of that. If you need to fetch data from a database, you probably want `useEffect` (as the documentation says, that's one of its chief purposes), but it's impossible to be more specific without more information.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify the issue @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is standard react lifecycle behavior. Your component will be mounted and then render (run alle the code inside your component). After rendering the first time it "listens" to changes to the values that you handle in your component and re-renders if any changes are detected.

Your case:

```
const initialArray  = [];
const [Items, setItems] = useState(initialArray)
initialArray.push("pushed item")
setItems(initialArray)
```

I see 2 bad things here:

1. You modify the array which you use as the initial value of your state and keep using that same array to update your state.
2. You push a new item and update the state on each render when calling `setItems(initialArray)`

Lets focus on the second one, since thats the one that causes your issues. If you want to avoid the endless render cycle then you should move your `setItems()` call to a method which doesn't run on each render. Before functional components this would be done in the `componentDidMount()` function. In a functional component this is done using the useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Your code here
}, [])
```

Notice the empty array supplied to useEffect. This array lists which dependencies should cause this useEffect to run. If you leave it empty it will only run once and act like the old componentDidMount() function.

So to solve your issue of endless rendering, you need to move `setItems()` into the useEffect hook.